# Recognize Alert with Selenium and HtmlUnitDriver or PhantomJsDriver

Tags: java, javascript, selenium, ghostdriver, htmlunit-driver

I use **Selenium 2.42.0** with **Java (in Eclipse)** and I need to use as **WebDriver** a headless browser like **HtmlUnit-driver (2.42.2)** or **PhantomJS (Ghostdriver)**. It`s important that I can handle alerts in Java (Eclipse), which i trigger on purpose for testing on the tested sites. 
I may close the Alert but **I need to recognize it** somehow in eclipse that there has been an Alert, like getting the Text of the alert or even an Exception that there is a alert present 
or like:

```
if(alert ==true)
  var_alert++;
```

With the **FireFoxdriver** it is easy but the Alert is not implemented yet in HtmlUnitDriver and PhantomJsdriver by Selenium:

```
try{
                WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
                wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
                Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
                System.out.println("Found Alert: " + alert.getText());
                alert.accept();
         }
         catch(Exception e){
             System.out.println("Exception " + e); 
         }
```

**Please help me. Thx!**